# Shared folder between QEMU Windows guest and Linux host with virtio-fs

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt, virtio

In QEMU 5.0 and kernel 5.4. [Virtio-FS(D)](https://virtio-fs.gitlab.io/) was introduced for better access to shared folder on Linux host.
It seems  guests access the shared folder using something like FUSE technology.

I found a guide for Linux guest setup at [libvirt.org](https://libvirt.org/kbase/virtiofs.html)

But can you access to shared folder from a Windows guest and how?

I found [WinFSP](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp), maybe that can be used?